# Delete keys form localStorage with loop

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a page where you can add and remove ingredients which will display in an unordered list. When the user clicks on "Find recipe!" the list items will be saved in separate keys in the localStorage.

[image]

Now I will delete the Carrot, Potato, Tomato and Chips and click on "Find Recipe!". Now the code will check how many li's are left and delete the rest.

```
var ingredients;
$('#findRecipe').click( function() {
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i <= $('#ulLeft li').length; i++) {
        ingredients = $('#ulLeft li:nth-child(' + i + ')').text();
        localStorage.setItem('ingredientsAvailable' + i, ingredients);
    }
    if(localStorage.key(i) !== null) {
        for(var j = i; j<=localStorage.length; j++ ) {
            localStorage.removeItem('ingredientsAvailable' + j);

        }
    }

});
```

But the code only deletes 2 keys in the localStorage. Doesn't matter how many I delete it only will delete 2 keys.

[image]

But when I do this a second time it WILL delete the right number.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove an item, the length changes. You should iterate backwards, like so:

```
for( var j = localStorage.length-1; j>=i; j--) {
```

This will ensure that the dynamic length won't affect you.

btw, you can put an array in `localStorage` if you run it through `JSON.stringify` (and `JSON.parse` to get it back), or by `join`ing it with a delimiter you know won't be in the elements (`|` is usually a good one) and `split`ting it later. Arrays are a LOT easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works almost:$ When I use this it will delete all the keys which I want it to delete EXEPT for the last one

Comment: Use `localStorage.length-2` then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://github.com/nbubna/store then you can just do store.clear(); and let the library worry about getting it correct (which it does, of course).